# Jquery SlideDown() function not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to slideUp and slideDown the gridview when I click the gridview list, but only slideUp is working.

This below is showing in script file.

```
$('.divname').SlideUp(
```

This below is not showing in script file

```
$('.divname').SlideDown(
```

Comment: They're case-sensitive. `slideDown()` and `slideUp()`. And in case you didn't make the typo mistake in your actual code, we still need a [mcve]

Comment: Try `.slideUp()` instead of `.SlideUp()`. I mean by first-letter will lowercase.

Comment: Until you get used to the names of various jQuery methods, it's best you copy/paste their exact names from the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/).

Answer (score 2):

They are case-sensitive, and should be used like so: `slideUp()` and `slideDown()` and not `SlideUp()` or `SlideDown()`.

See examples below. The red `div` uses `slideUp()` and the yellow `div` uses `SlideUp()`.

```js
$('#test1').mouseover(function() { 
  $(this).slideUp(); 
});
$('#test2').mouseover(function() { 
  $(this).SlideUp(); 
});
```

```css
#test1 { margin: 1em; border: 1px solid black; width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: red; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; }
#test2 { margin: 1em; border: 1px solid black; width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: yellow; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 150px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test1">test1</div>
<div id="test2">test2</div>
```